# Using a Flickr stream as a Windows 7 background slideshow?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, flickr

Is there an app that will let me choose a Flickr photostream to be used as background slide show in Windows 7?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [John's Background Switcher](http://johnsadventures.com/software/backgroundswitcher/)

> John’s Background Switcher (or JBS for
>   short) periodically changes the
>   background image on your computer
>   (like every hour or every day) to
>   something interesting. You can specify
>   which pictures to choose from:
>
> - Individual pictures on your computer.
> - Folders containing pictures on your    computer such as ‘My Pictures’.-
> - Flickr photo sharing – selecting    pictures by person, tags, sets or
>     just plain random. You never know
>     what you’re going to get next!-
> - Facebook – your friends photos on your desktop!
> - Vladstudio wallpapers – choose from the coolest wallpapers on the net!
> - Any Media RSS feed – choose pictures from sites like DeviantArt,
>     Photobucket, LOLCats and Zooomr
>     amongst many others!
> - Phanfare web albums – keep up to date with your friends and family.
> - smugmug photo galleries – yours, your friends, anybody’s!
> - Picasa Web Albums – choose from specific albums or any search text.
> - Webshots – if you’re a Webshots user, you can choose from your online
>     or downloaded photos and collections.
> - Google Image Search – get pictures from anywhere across the internet.
> - Bing Image Search – not a Google fanboy? Then Bing is for you!
> - Yahoo! image search – the internet is your oyster!

Comment: As of v4.8 it does 500px as well!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Bing Wallpaper Theme](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-a-bing-wallpaper-desktop-slideshow-in-windows-7/) that uses an RSS feed to pull down images. You can try replacing the RSS feed with the feed for the photostream and see if that works.